# How to effectively use foreach in laravel-livewire in a table when the data dynamically changes?

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I've been struggling with the `foreach` blade directive when combined with Laravel-Livewire and dynamically changing data rendered in an html table.

Specific scenario:

- A table is presented to the user
- Each row of the table includes a clickable icon that toggles a variable associated with that row
- Toggling this icon visibly removes the row from the table

It sounds simple enough but I cannot get it to work correctly.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class UnreconciledServices extends Component
{

    public $services;
    


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.unreconciled-services');
    }


    //
    // receives an invoice number and changes the "reconciled" value for the $aaaServices record to true
    //
   

    public function test($a)
    {
    }
}
```

This is pretty simple - there is a function called "test" that accepts a variable (the function does nothing at all) and there is a collection of records called $services that has been passed in from the parent.

The blade file is as follows:

```
<div>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%">

                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Service Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Call #
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Payment
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($services as $service)
                    {{-- <span wire:key="{{$service->invoice_number}}"> --}}

                        {{-- @if ($service->reconciled == false) --}}
                            <tr  id="{{$service->invoice_number}}" class="text-center" style="{{ $service->reconciled == 1 ? 'display:none' : 'show'}}">
                                <td>
                                    {{-- <input class="m-2" type="checkbox"> --}}
                                    {{-- <span class="m-2"><i class="far fa-trash-alt text-red-500"></i></span> --}}

                                    <span wire:key="{{$service->invoice_number}}" wire:click="test('{{$service->invoice_number}}')" class="m-2 cursor-pointer"><i class="lm-2 rm-2 fas fa-plus text-green-500"></i></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{$service->invoice_date}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{$service->call_number}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{$service->service_price}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {{-- @endif --}}
                    {{-- </span> --}}
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is a simple table with 4 columns. The 1st is a clickable icon, the other 3 are data.  Rows should only be visible if the "reconciled" boolean is 0.

When initially rendered, the appropriate records are displayed (there are 2 that qualify and 177 that do not).  However, as soon as I click the icon - even when the function it links to has zero actual content - all records are suddenly visible *except* for the one that I've just hidden.

Looking at the html change when I click the icon, the tag changes from

`<tr id="21031251674" class="text-center" style="display:none">`

to

`<tr id="21031253205" class="text-center" style="show">`.

I have tried using livewire keys, though I'm not sure how this would affect the functionality since I'm not rendering components, but rather data driven html.

Surely someone else has encountered this and overcome. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Seems like theres some info missing here @scott_p. How are you actually aiming to hide the row? What's rendering the table? Another Livewire component?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the delay. This whole thread should be deleted as bone-headed.  But it was written in earnest...

When all was said and done, I was unclear on the differences b/w an html / ajax - based approach such as livewire and something more javascript-based such as Vue.  I was expecting functionality that didn't exist in the framework as I was attempting to use it.

To solve the problem, I moved towards individual row items being components in and of themselves, using `emit` to communicate between components and adjust the backend data source.

Once I embraced the html / ajax approach and stopped trying to force / expect javascript functionality & dom manipulation then all was well.  Just a mindset difference from what I am familiar with, and it took me some time to turn the corner.